# Function that return average depth of a binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have the following binary tree structure, and I'd like to write a function that calculates and return the **average depth** of objects in a tree.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

- calculate the total height of the tree
- divide total height/total nodes

However, I'm getting nowhere, and would love to have any helpful suggestions in terms of how can I go about implementing the algorithm.

```
typedef struct tree_s tree_t;
struct tree_s {
    int num;
    tree_t *left;
    tree_t *right;
}


int total_depth(tree_t *tree, int accum) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return accum; /* done */
    }
    accum = accum + total_depth(tree->left, accum+1);
    accum = accum + total_depth(tree->right, accum+1);
    return accum;
}
```

There seems to be something wrong with my recursive function total_depth, as i'm getting a ridiculously large number.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `return` somewhere in the function? And what is `accum_depth`?

Comment: What's the definition of average depth of a tree anyway? Is it Sum{depth(v) | for all  nodes v}/#nodes?

Comment: You shouldn't add the depths of left and right subtrees but choose and return the larger of the two (after adding 1).

Comment: Thanks for noticing my mistakes @JoachimPileborg, I've corrected them in the above question :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. From my understanding, average depth of objects in the tree is equal to the sum of depth from each nodes / total object in the tree?

Comment: Yes I was wrong in my previous comment. The average depth is not simply the sum of average of left / right divided by two, you have to weight in the number of branches in each sub-branch

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway! @Eregrith All good :)

Comment: Average depth might in fact simply be defined as *The depth of the binary tree if it was balanced*, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not too sure about that though. I'm just trying to come up with a very basic algorithm that could calculate the average depth of any kind of binary tree, since binary tree are not always balanced anyway. Any link that would be helpful to read on to calculate the depth of a balanced binary tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing something like:

```
int total_depth(tree_t *tree, int accum)
{
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    return accum +
        total_depth(tree->left, accum + 1) +
        total_depth(tree->right, accum + 1);
}

total_depth(root, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have a typo up there as the int variable depth is not declared in the function. I'm assuming that it's meant to be the variable accum instead? However, the total_depth function does not return the right value. :(

Comment: Yes, I meant `accum`. You need to get the cumulative depth of all nodes, don't you?

Comment: Yes. Your function is almost right, however it seems to return additional sum of accum instead of the correct ones. I tried to play around with it and realised what actually went wrong. As the recursive function keeps looping until it reaches the leave node (where the node has no child node), it returns accum. Instead, it should return 0 if tree == NULL. Thanks for your help! Everything works like a charm now!